# How to solve Virto Commerce Theme Missing Error?

Tags: virtocommerce

I had deployed the Virto Commerce Platform and storefront on my local machine with IIS. everything went well but when i open store front it is saying

Virto Commerce storefront has been successfully deployed
Looks like you're missing a theme :(

We looked for 'index.liquid' view in the following locations

```
Themes\Electronics\default\templates
Themes\Electronics\default\snippets
Themes\Electronics\default\layout
Themes\Electronics\default\assets
```

It simple to fix: follow our instructions to download and correctly configure theme for your storefront.

I had tried almost all options mentioned here but not able to sort out issue.

I think iam doing something wrong with connection string in appsettings.json or iam making some mistake in linking the platform directory to storefront theme .

This is my connection string

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ContentConnectionString": "provider=LocalStorage;rootPath=~/cms-content"
```

I tried to point this to local directory of my installation

```
C:\vc-platform\VirtoCommerce.Platform.Web\App_Data\cms-content
```

becoz of this i had made a virtual directory inside the storefront folder in iis manager.

but again when i assign this value application is not starting by saying Http error.

can anybody help in sorting out this issue?

Comment: Set this value for setting will be enough  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ContentConnectionString": "provider=LocalStorage;rootPath=C:\vc-platform\VirtoCommerce.Platform.Web\App_Data\cms-content"

Comment: thanks @tatarincev it saved my day. both are working great....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set this value for setting will be enough

**appsettings.json**

`....
"ConnectionStrings": { "ContentConnectionString": "provider=LocalStorage;rootPath=C:\vc-platform\VirtoCommerce.Platform.Web\App_Data\cms-content"
...`